# how can i add a font family in in pdf itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller, fonts, itext

Here is the code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();




 sb.Append("<table border='1'  style='border-
          collapse:collapse;width:100%;margin-top:10px;font-family: 'Source Sans 
       Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 
       14px !important;font-weight: 300;'>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td align='center' style='padding:5px;'>");
            sb.Append("Question");
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("<td align='center' style='padding:5px;'>");
            sb.Append("<h4>Answer</h4>");
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");

            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td style='padding:5px;'>");
            sb.Append("Gender");
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("<td style='padding:5px;'>");
            sb.Append(result.Rows[0]["Question1"].ToString());
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");

            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td style='padding:5px;'>");
            sb.Append("Age Group");
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("<td style='padding:5px;'>");
            sb.Append(result.Rows[0]["Question2"].ToString());
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);

            pdfDoc.Open();

            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();

            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";                     
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "; filename=Survey.pdf");

            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            Response.Close();

        }
```

Here how can i add the font family :'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important and font-weight: 400; for all the text in this pdf.

How to add font family and font style in pdf itextsharp.

I am using some code but not working. The style in the sb.Append in table is not working in pdf page in .net c#. I am trying the below code but not working:

```
//Font fon = FontFactory.GetFont("Source Sans Pro", 14);
                //Font fon1 = FontFactory.GetFont("Helvetica Neue", 14);
                //Font fon2 = FontFactory.GetFont("Helvetica", 14);
                //Font fon3 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 14);
                //Font fon4 = FontFactory.GetFont("sans-serif", 14);
```

Any Suggestions??

Comment: `HTMLWorker` is obsolete. As explained in [the introduction of the new HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml), it will bring you nothing but frustration. You should upgrade to iText 7 and pdfHTML. Read [chapter 6](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-pdfhtml) to find out how to use fonts. The examples are in Java, but iText 7 for Java and iText 7 for .NET have pretty much the same syntax.

Comment: Sir is there any other technique or method that can add the string builder sb html to the style??

Comment: As I said: `HTMLWorker` is obsolete. It has been abandoned. It doesn't support CSS, so all your `style` attributes are ignored. There is no cure for that, except following my advice and upgrade to iText 7 + pdfHTML. `HTMLWorker` was written in a very poor way, it couldn't be extended to support CSS without rewriting it from scratch (which is what eventually happened).